# Transaction timeout set on Websphere

Tags: transactions, ejb, websphere, settimeout

I work on Websphere application server,
as seen in the code below , this is the simple gateway Bean, I call dispatcherRequest method from another method with lookup,but the transaction starts every time I call,but transaction time-out set default value on websphere. I want to change timeout with code , I would like to mention that we have to use Container transaction management.

```
@Stateless(name = "EJBGatewayServiceCMT")
public class EJBGatewayServiceBean implements EJBGatewayService {

@Resource
private SessionContext ctx;


@Override
@TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.REQUIRES_NEW)
public void dispachRequestObject(Object inputData, Object outputData, Dispacher dispacher) {
    try {
        dispacher.doDispach(inputData, outputData);
    } catch (Throwable t) {
        ctx.setRollbackOnly();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, your two requirements (setting transaction timeout in code, and using container managed transactions) are incompatible and so this isn't possible.  In order to have your code set the transaction timeout, you need to be using a bean managed transaction, in which case you can use `ejbContext.getUserTransaction().setTransactionTimeout(seconds)` prior to beginning the transaction.  With container managed transactions, the transaction is already started by the container by the time it enters your method and it is too late to change the timeout for it.